# SharedPreferences on iOS 4

Tags: android, iphone, ios, ios4, sharedpreferences

I am looking for a way to store data about a user in iOS 4 that is similar to SharedPreferences in Android. Android's SharedPreferences basically stores key value pairs for an application and only that application can access it.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Does iOS 4 have something built in that can accomplish what SharedPreferences does in Android?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` is your choice.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Typically you'd like to:

- use standard user defaults (`[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`)
- store preferences using `-set*:ForKey:` (* being int, double, bool, dictionary, object...)
- retrieve them using `-*ForKey:`
- `-synchronize` when needed

Comment: This looks like what i want. Ill do some testing and get back to you.